# How to re-enable being found by Google

Tags: search-engines

A long time ago when I installed WordPress I enabled the (no robots) or something like it, anyhow Google doesn't show additional details when searching for my site.

How do I reverse this?

EDIT:

My html source:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
```

My php Source:

```
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution myself:

Settings -> Reading -> Discourage search engines from indexing this site (must be blank)(bottom of page)